# Make -- Changing system-wide implicit rules

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Say I have a file `foo.c` and there is no `Makefile`, when I call `make foo` the implicit rules of `make` conveniently kick in and compile `foo.c`. Is there an easy way to add a couple flags such as `-g` and `-Wall` into the implicit rules?

I've seen that I could use pattern rules in a `Makefile`, but I'd rather have these flags in the implicit rules apply across the entirety of my local machine (mac OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an article for what you're looking for:

http://seshbot.com/blog/2014/06/16/make-with-no-makefile-for-c-plus-plus-playgrounds/

Basically, it tells you to set the environment variables to the flags you always want to be passed by default

Comment: Dont just link the article, add a short example here. What if the link dies?

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend `CFLAGS` to the command line:

```
CFLAGS='-g -Wall' make foo
```